# Big data zip on amazon S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, cloud, s3cmd

I have large amount of data stored on amazon S3 in the forms of objects.

like i Have user which have 200+ GB of photos (about 100000+ objects) stored on amazon S3. each object is a photo , each object size is average 5MB.

Now I want to give a user a link to download data.

Currently what i am doing.

1. Using [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) i copy all the objects from [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) to [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/).
2. and then using **ZIP command** or **TAR Command** i create a
   ZIp.
3. After Zip process is complete i move the zip file back to the S3.
4. and Then create a singed link that i send to user as an email.

But this process takes a long long time, most of the time it gives out of memory issues, storage issues and this process is very slow.

I need to Know

1. Is there any way that i can boost this process time.
2. Is there any third party service/tool where i can create fast zip
   of my files and send to user.
3. or any other 3rd party solution, I am ready to pay for it.

Comment: How did you fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using EMR (Elastic Map Reducer and the S3distCp) that can be helpful in your required situation, for EMR you have to create a cluster. and the running your job.

Answer (score 1):

The direction what you are following at high level is correct. However there isn't any straight forward answer which may possibly solve your problem in a single shot.

These are the things which you can try doing

1. Ask your user to create a AWS account ( or create an IAM user ) and provide a read-only access to that user / account
2. During the process of uploading to S3 you can group the photos in the bundles of few 50s or 100s compress it and then put in S3 ( from EC2 i.e. during creation of the media itself)
3. Export to external media from S3 using - [Amazon Import / Export](http://aws.amazon.com/importexport/faqs/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can EMR(Elastic Map Reducer) or Redshift or glacier can be helpfull in this regards?

Comment: the problem here is about the delivery of the bulky data, whereas EMR, Redshift are candidates for storage or processing; so they would be poor choice for the use case.

Answer (score 1):

S3DistCP is tool that can greatly help in cases such as this.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html

S3DistCP can copy from and to S3 using an EMR Cluster instead of a single instance and compress objects on the fly.

However, in "big data" processing, the user will probably have a better experience if you either create the bundles in advance proactively or start the process asynchronously on-demand and notify the user on completion with the download link.